SPI issue in arduino and STM32F4 connection
I wanted to play with SPI on STM32f4 nucleo (made it MASTER) and communicate with slave - arduino pro micro.
Idea is that whatever i type on serial terminal connected  to nucleo is passed to arduino via SPI and read back on other serial terminal.
Soft on STM32 is configured with SPI on a full duplex and with software chip-select.
Setup:

usb->serial to nucleo (ft232) (only tx and rx)
usb->serial to arudino (cp1202) (power supply included, CTS & DTR as well)
salae logic state analyzer
supply to nucleo

Nucleo and arduino are connected  with each other via SPI (4 lines)
Problem is - with setup above, connected to Mac via USB3.0 to 2.0 expander,
i got garbage on SPI MOSI (clock is ok but data is either 0x00 or 0xFF)
however:
If i unplug 2, data send (MOSI) from nucleo over SPI is correct (checked on salae), see image below:

case when everything is powered from USB:

im not sure where now to seek answer, so any hits appriciated. I tested communication with two arduinos (master & same slave as above) and everything is fine.

Are they both 3.3V MCUs so they have same voltage on their SPI pins? How did you connect the data wires, MOSI to MOSI or MOSI to MISO.

arduino for sure is 3.3V, regarding STM32 - refering to spec: I/Os are CMOS & TTL tolerant, however Vdd=3.3V
